# How to get a @html.Checkbox to update a @html.dropdownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following checkbox:

```
@Html.CheckBox("Norm", false, new { @class = "checkbox" })
```

Once this is checked, I want it to auto update my dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectedCore", (SelectList)ViewBag.CoreSheets)
```

The dropdown selectlist is populated from my controller like this,

```
ViewBag.CoreSheets = new SelectList(db.CoreSheets, "sheetID", "Abb");
```

So in summary, I want to click the check box and have the current dropdown value be updated.

Cheers,

B
N J

Comment: what? im using ASP.net mvc 5

Comment: add ASP.net mvc to tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@Html.CheckBox("Norm", false, new { @class = "checkbox",@onclick="clickNorm()" })
<script type="text/javascript">
 function clickNorm(){
   $.ajax({
       url:'@Url.Action("LoadSelectedCoreList")'
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(res){
        if(res && res.length>0){
            $('#selectedCore).empty();
            $.each(res,function(index,item){
                $('#selectedCore').append(new Option(item.Abb,item.sheetID));
            });
         }
        }
      });
</script>
```

In Coltroller

```
public ActionResult LoadSelectedCoreList()
    {
        var selectedCoreList=..
        return Json(selectedCoreList,
      JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: When you are calling Var selected core list, is this where id specify the id of dropdown i want it to select?

Comment: var selectedCoreList = ... is the code you need for loading CoreSheets that every item in list has id and name

Comment: please modify javascript code , I write it only without copy paste

Comment: theres errors with the javascript! and it wont let me call AllowBehaviorGet

Comment: whattttttttttttttttttttttt?

Comment: JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by doing the following,

Check box

```
            @Html.CheckBox("Norm", false, new { @class = "checkbox" })
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#Norm").on("click", function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        $("#kammcoreauto").val(1);
                        $("#kammfaceauto").val(1);
                        $("#spacecoreauto").val(1);
                        $("#Washercoreauto").val(1);
                        $("#IsoCoreauto").val(1);
                        $("#IsoFaceauto").val(1);
                      }
                });
            });
                        </script>
```

and this just refers to the id of the dropdowns that you can add like this

```
  @Html.DropDownList("selectedCore", (SelectList)ViewBag.CoreSheets, new { id = "kammcoreauto" })
```

Big Thanks to everyone who tried to help